# Skype cutting out on Samsung Galaxy Ace III

Tags: skype, voip

I've had my phone (Samsung Galaxy Ace III) for around 3 weeks now. Ever since I received it I instantly installed Skype and for some reason, when ever I'm calling any of my friends their voices cut out.

I have borrowed several other devices in my house to try and see if it was a local/generic problem but that was inconclusive as Skype worked fine on all of them.

It's really quite irritating when I'm trying to talk to my friend and when he replies I don't hear him, either at all or only a little bit. What's my problem?

Also I've tried re-installing Skype several times as well as cleaning caches etc.

Comment: Bump, needs a reply.

Comment: I guess that's what bounties are for, but first you should earn more reputation points... maybe answering someone else's questions?

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Many factors can affect Skype:

- Try to move closer to your router/modem
- Close any unnecessary applications, and then go to Task Manager > RAM > Clear RAM
- Boot your device into recovery mode, and click on "Wipe cache partition". None of your data will be lost, don't worry.